# How to post in facebook fanpage automatically from my website?

Tags: facebook

How to post in facebook fanpage automatically from my website ?

for example when i update new post in my website and i need to post in facebook fan page automatically....

Answer (score 0):

I believe Facebook offers a certain number of APIs which would allow you to integrate Facebook into your own website to some degree; you can always try their [dev centre](https://developers.facebook.com/).
As far as I know, however, you can only post to Facebook through social networks like Twitter (see: [linking a Twitter account to Facebook](https://apps.facebook.com/twitter/)), or through Facebook apps you've developed yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create facebook app and use the app secret key and and API key  in facebook SDK
script for automatic posting. for more details click the following link. I think this may help you.   http://www.damnsemicolon.com/php/auto-post-facebook-with-facebook-sdk

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.